# Brackets annoying "External Changes" popup

Tags: adobe-brackets

Welcome everyone,
I use Brackets for several months but now I'm working on important, personal project. For this reason I decided to synchronize it with Dropbox (I'm working on many computers and I'm scared of losing my whole progress). Everything works perfectly, but whenever Dropbox wants to sync its database with my "Dropbox" folder, Brackets shows me annoying "External Changes" error. Is there any way to avoid or disable it, because with that is less fun with coding ;)

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVvS3.png)

PS. I use Brackets "autosave" extension

Comment: I am also facing this very annoying thing. And it ONLY happens during JS coding. Writing CSS or HTML code doesn't lead to this behavior. Can't understand why tho, but writing JS code doesn't make fun like this :(

Comment: I disabled autosave and everything works perfectly :)

Comment: When I write in js it doesn't appear... Check if you have some extensions making Brackets to evoke that popup

Comment: Well I have autosave activated as I wish to use it. Funnily I didn't get this behavior as of the last couple days while programming quite a bit in JS - without changing anything. Didn't occure even once, why ever. Hope it stays like that :D